# Custom control moving another element

Tags: c#

I'm trying to create my custom control for:

[image] (numeric updown)
I want to use the value in the control to offset the position of a certain element (which is set using "targetElement" on the control's properties). But since settings are stored as strings, I only have the string value.

For example: If the user sets "targetElement" as label1, I want to offset the position of label1 using BobbyUpDown1.targetElement.Location.x, but since targetElement is storing a string of the ID of the element, it won't let me do that.

How can I grab the reference to the label1 (that the user input) from the targetElement property?

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

```
Control c = this.Controls["YourLabelName"];
if (c != null)
{
   c.Location = new Point(newXLocationForYourLabel, c.Location.Y);
}
```

Here `this` is the `Form`